# Using NOT IN in dynamic SQL with sp_executesql and parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Say I have this table:

```
create table CodeTable (
    CodeType int, 
    CodeVal char(2), 
    CodeDesc varchar(50))

insert CodeTable values 
    (1, 'AB', 'Desc for AB'), 
    (1, 'CD', 'Desc for CD'), 
    (1, 'DE', 'Desc for DE'),
    (2, 'FG', 'Desc for FG'),
    (2, 'HI', 'Desc for HI')
```

I want a stored procedure to get values from the table, but to exclude specified codes if needed:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCodes]
    @CodeType int,
    @NotInList varchar(100) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @sql nvarchar(1000) = '
        select CodeType, CodeVal, CodeDesc
        from CodeTable
        where CodeType = @CodeType'

    if isnull(@NotInList, '') <> ''
        set @sql += ' and CodeVal not in (@NotInList)'

    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@CodeType int, @NotInList varchar(100)', @CodeType, @NotInList
END
```

These work as desired:

```
exec [dbo].[GetCodes] 1, ''
exec [dbo].[GetCodes] 1, 'AB'
```

But these gives me all codes:

```
exec [dbo].[GetCodes] 1, 'AB,CD'
exec [dbo].[GetCodes] 1, '''AB'',''CD'''
```

What am I missing? I know I could do this with `sp_executesql` without the params and build the complete SQL string, but I'd like to know if I can do it with the params. Thanks!

Comment: for future use, you may want to consider using "table valued parameters", So you could pass @NotInList as a table, then JOIN or perform a WHERE NOT EXISTS  on that table. This can save you having to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..... This clever piece of code takes away the pain of using a function to split the comma delimited values. yet its clever and quick.

Also the variable `@NotInList` is optional , if you pass a value to it , it will be added in the actual select clause else it is just ignored.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCodes]
    @CodeType int,
    @NotInList varchar(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @xml xml,@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

    set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@NotInList,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

 SET @SQL = N'select CodeType, CodeVal, CodeDesc
              from CodeTable
              where CodeType = @CodeType '
          + CASE WHEN @NotInList IS NOT NULL THEN 
          N' AND CodeVal NOT IN (
                                select r.value(''.'',''varchar(max)'') as item
                                from @xml.nodes(''//root/r'') as records(r)
                                )' ELSE N'' END 

    exec sp_executesql @sql
                    , N'@CodeType int, @xml XML'
                    , @CodeType
                    , @Xml
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter passed to sp_executesql is treated as one single value, not as a list.   so when you pass in 'AB,CD' your query becomes

```
      select CodeType, CodeVal, CodeDesc  from CodeTable where CodeType = 1 and CodeVal not in ( 'AB,CD' )
```

See the answer to the question below for workaround options

[sp_executesql with 'IN' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600389/sp-executesql-with-in-statement)

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I couldn't find that answer when I searched.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way that I do these kind of things when it comes to a `dynamic` list of items.

I have a table function which will take a concatenated string and then split it into a table for me like so.

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] (@Value NVARCHAR(MAX), @SplitCharacter NVARCHAR(1), @AddWildCard BIT = 1)
RETURNS @Results TABLE 
(
    String NVARCHAR(MAX)    
    , Sequence INT 
)

AS 

BEGIN 

    DECLARE @Splitter NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SplitPosition INT
    DECLARE @SequenceNumber INT 
    SET @SequenceNumber = 1
--  PRINT 'ENTERING LOOP SPLITTER'
    WHILE   LEN(@Value) > 0
    BEGIN       
--      PRINT 'GETTING FIRST POSITION OF SPLITTER CHARACTER'
        SET @SplitPosition =  CHARINDEX(@SplitCharacter,@Value) 
        IF  @SplitPosition = 0 
        BEGIN 
            SET @SplitPosition = LEN(@Value) 
        END 

        SET @Splitter = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(@Value),1,@SplitPosition),@SplitCharacter,'')

        INSERT INTO  @Results 
        SELECT  
            CASE 
                WHEN @AddWildCard = 1 THEN 
                    '%' + RTRIM(LTRIM(@Splitter)) +  '%' 
                ELSE    
                    RTRIM(LTRIM(@Splitter)) 
            END 
        , @SequenceNumber



        SET 
            @Value =    CASE 
                            WHEN @SplitPosition > 0 THEN  
                                SUBSTRING(@Value,(@SplitPosition + 1 ),LEN(@Value)) 
                            ELSE 
                                '' 
                        END 
        SET 
            @SequenceNumber = @SequenceNumber + 1
    END 

--  PRINT 'RETURNING VALUE'

    RETURN 

END
```

so for example if we had you first scenario of:

```
exec [dbo].[GetCodes] 1, 'AB,CD'
```

we would call the splitString function inside your where clause

then using a slight mod of your code above:

```
DECLARE @CodeType int
DECLARE @NotInList NVARCHAR(max) 
SET @CodeType = 1
SET @NotInList = 'AB,CD'

declare @CodeTable table  (
    CodeType int, 
    CodeVal char(2), 
    CodeDesc varchar(50))

insert @CodeTable values 
    (1, 'AB', 'Desc for AB'), 
    (1, 'CD', 'Desc for CD'), 
    (1, 'DE', 'Desc for DE'),
    (2, 'FG', 'Desc for FG'),
    (2, 'HI', 'Desc for HI')

  select CodeType, CodeVal, CodeDesc
        from @CodeTable
        where 
            CodeType = @CodeType
            AND 
                (CASE WHEN LEN(ISNULL(@NotInList,0)) > 0 THEN 
                    CASE WHEN CodeVal NOT IN (SELECT string FROM dbo.SplitString(@NotInList, ',',0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                ELSE 
                    1 END ) = 1
```

doing this means you don't have to run sp_executesql